# Issuing Dirty Reads in a transaction in Spring Data JPA with Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm quite surprised that PostgreSQL removed Dirty Reads (Read Uncommited Isolation Level)in 9.6 (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html, but it was supported in at least 9.1 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html).

Now, my problem is a controller method that performs:

- Check if entity exists with findById()
- save() a new entity if not

So I had wrapped the method within a `@Transactional(readOnly = false, isolation_level = READ_UNCOMMITED)`, which is what led me to realize the isolation was not working, since second thread/transaction does not find the id even if it's been created by the first in case both transactions are still not committed and therefore, the code tries to insert the id twice.

**So, how can this be solved with current standards, should we really mess with synchronization? Treat an AlreadyExistsException as control flow, and lose performance as we replicate the process?**

Comment: Postgres **never** supported dirty reads. And the 9.1 documentation you link to clearly states: "*When you select the level Read Uncommitted you really get Read Committed*"

Comment: If you weren't limited by your obfuscation layer you could simply do `insert ... on conflict ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mvcc NEVER supported dirty reads. But I can see it clearly stated in docs from as early as 8.0:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/transaction-iso.html

> In PostgreSQL, you can request any of the four standard transaction
>   isolation levels. But internally, there are only two distinct
>   isolation levels, which correspond to the levels Read Committed and
>   Serializable. When you select the level Read Uncommitted you really
>   get Read Committed

and from 9.1 `Repeatable read` added:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html

> In PostgreSQL, you can request any of the four standard transaction
>   isolation levels. But internally, there are only three distinct
>   isolation levels, which correspond to the levels Read Committed,
>   Repeatable Read, and Serializable. When you select the level Read
>   Uncommitted you really get Read Committed

**update**
as a_horse_with_no_name noticed - internally, there are only two distinct isolation levels as from 7.1:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/transaction-iso.html

> Postgres offers the read committed and serializable isolation levels.

thanks to @Laurenz another note:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html

> Prior to PostgreSQL version 9.1, a request for the Serializable
>   transaction isolation level provided exactly the same behavior
>   described here (`REPEATABLE READ`). To retain the legacy Serializable behavior, Repeatable
>   Read should now be requested.

or just quoting @Laurenz himself:

> In 9.1, the old SERIALIZABLE was renamed to REPEATABLE READ because it
>   did not guarantee that there is an equivalent serialized execution
>   order. In the same release, "real" SERIALIZABLE was added, which is
>   something quite different.

Comment: This should be clarified. In 9.1, the old `SERIALIZABLE` was *renamed* to `REPEATABLE READ` because it did not guarantee that there is an equivalent serialized execution order. In the same release, "real" `SERIALIZABLE` was added, which is something quite different. PostgreSQL has never supported dirty reads.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This is really interesting, but I am not sure this can really help me solving the issue

Comment: well, to avoid dupes, you can use upsert as suggested in comments - it will be practically no additional cost and fully atomic. And regarding the sentence in bold - I don't think I understand enough to say something on the fundamental problem. Also I have no knowledge of spring/jpa - I could advise only on postgres side...